# Cannot change div height after adding Layout

Tags: html, css, razor

I have a razor view web page that has a `div` that i fill data into it in some way (lazy load, or loop, doesn't matter).

If i dont use a Layout, IE:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Then the `div` will use my configured height, and also shows a scrollbar if needed (using `overflow: auto`)

However, when i add a layout, even an empty one, i cannot seem to modify the `div`'s height, which causes it to take all the screen from the layout to the bottom, and shows no scrolling.

What disabled my ability to change the height?

(the `div` im loading data into is div id `container`)

***index.cshtml:***

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 15%;
    }

    .Good {
        background-color: green
    }

    .Bad {
        background-color: red
    }

    #container {
        background: #eee;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden;">

    <div>
        <div>
            <h3 id="Progression"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; overflow: auto;">

        </div>
        <div id="progress" style="display: none; height: 20%">
            <h4>Loading...</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

***_Layout.cshtml:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .main-header {
        background: url(/images/bg-header.png) transparent repeat-x 0 0;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <header class="main-header" role="banner">
        <div>
            <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home">
                <img src="/images/COMPANY-logo.png" style="background-color:white;" alt="Home">
            </a>

        </div>
    </header>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Empty _Layout.cshtml:*** (having issues with this layout as well)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .main-header {
        background: url(/images/bg-header.png) transparent repeat-x 0 0;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Generated page (The empty layout was used):***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .main-header {
        background: url(/images/bg-header.png) transparent repeat-x 0 0;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>

<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 15%;
    }

    .Good {
        background-color: green
    }

    .Bad {
        background-color: red
    }

    #container {
        background: #eee;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <script src="/JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="overflow: hidden;">

    <div>
        <div>
            <h3 id="Progression"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; overflow: auto;">

        </div>
        <div id="progress" style="display: none; height: 20%">
            <h4>Loading...</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var pageSize = 50;
    var pageIndex = 0;
    var totalItemsDisplayed = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        lazyLoadCards(0);
        $('#container').scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            var scrollHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight');
            var clientHeight = $(this).prop('clientHeight');

            if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight) {
                pageIndex++;
                lazyLoadCards(pageIndex);
            }
        });

        function lazyLoadCards(index) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/AllCards/OnScrollEnd',
                data: { "startIndex": index, "size": pageSize },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        totalItemsDisplayed += data.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                                data[i].cardNumber +
                                "</h2>");
                        }

                        updateProgression();
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#progress").show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $("#progress").hide();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error while retrieving data!");
                }
            });
        }

        function loadCards(index) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/AllCards/OnScrollEnd',
                data: { "startIndex": index, "size": pageSize },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        totalItemsDisplayed += data.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                                data[i].cardNumber +
                                "</h2>");
                        }
                        updateProgression();
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            loadCards(index + 1);
                        }
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#progress").show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $("#progress").hide();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error while retrieving data!");
                }
            });
        }

        function updateProgression() {
            $('#Progression').text("Displaying " +  totalItemsDisplayed + " Cards out of " +  6930);
        }
    });

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Visual to see current output and desired outcome:***
(Note that thetext inside the gray box is just  elements with some text. thats what the ajax call does)
[image: Visual to see current output]

***Generated code after adding @section and @style and removing body everyone besides _Layout***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .main-header {
            background: url(/images/bg-header.png) transparent repeat-x 0 0;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 15%;
        }

        .Good {
            background-color: green
        }

        .Bad {
            background-color: red
        }

        #container {
            background: #eee;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<header class="main-header" role="banner">
    <div>
        <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home">
            <img src="/images/COMPANY-logo.png" style="background-color:white;" alt="Home">
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
<div>

<div>
    <div>
        <h3 id="Progression"></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; overflow: visible;">

    </div>
    <div id="progress" style="display: none; height: 20%">
        <h4>Loading...</h4>
    </div>
</div>




</div>

    <script src="/JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var pageSize = 50;
    var pageIndex = 0;
    var totalItemsDisplayed = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        lazyLoadCards(0);
        $('#container').scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            var scrollHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight');
            var clientHeight = $(this).prop('clientHeight');

            if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight) {
                pageIndex++;
                lazyLoadCards(pageIndex);
            }
        });

        function lazyLoadCards(index) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/AllCards/OnScrollEnd',
                data: { "startIndex": index, "size": pageSize },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        totalItemsDisplayed += data.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                                data[i].cardNumber +
                                "</h2>");
                        }

                        updateProgression();
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#progress").show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $("#progress").hide();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error while retrieving data!");
                }
            });
        }

        function loadCards(index) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/AllCards/OnScrollEnd',
                data: { "startIndex": index, "size": pageSize },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        totalItemsDisplayed += data.length;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $("#container").append("<h2>" +
                                data[i].cardNumber +
                                "</h2>");
                        }
                        updateProgression();
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            loadCards(index + 1);
                        }
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#progress").show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $("#progress").hide();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error while retrieving data!");
                }
            });
        }

        function updateProgression() {
            $('#Progression').text("Displaying " +  totalItemsDisplayed + " Cards out of " +  6930);
        }
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put the generated HTML in your post?

Comment: I can tell you at least one thing. You shouldn't have style, head and body tags anywhere other than your layout. You should be using sections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Sections allow you to add styles, scripts, etc. on the layout. You can't have the head and body tags anywhere except the layout page.

**Empty _Layout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        .main-header {
            background: url(/images/bg-header.png) transparent repeat-x 0 0;
        }
    </style>
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
@section Styles {
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 15%;
    }

    .Good {
        background-color: green
    }

    .Bad {
        background-color: red
    }

    #container {
        background: #eee;
    }
</style>
}

<div>
    <div>
        <h3 id="Progression"></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; overflow: auto;">

    </div>
    <div id="progress" style="display: none; height: 20%">
        <h4>Loading...</h4>
    </div>
</div>  
@section Scripts {
        <script src="/JQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
}
```

**UPDATE**

You need to make the following change:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;height: 155px;overflow: scroll;display: block;">
```

You can't use a percentage for height unless you add `position:absolute;`. If you only want the vertical scroll bar, you'll need to use `overflow-y:scroll;` instead.

Comment: Im still left with the same problem, only now i have page scrollbar instead of div scrollbar (i dont want page scrollbar..)

Comment: I need to see the HTML as generated, after your Ajax call, or If you could replace the Ajax call with JSON. Without having populated data, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Added HTML as generated. Also added a picture that hopefully will explain my situation a little better. Also please see the note - the ajax call simply generates <h2> tags with text into the div (id'ed as container)

Comment: it looks like switching from percentage to pixels fixes it, thanks

Comment: @TomerSomething Good! Do you think you can mark my answer as the accepted one? That way everyone knows there is a solution.